# How can I make this if else, into a one liner, if true, Show an `<a>`, else show a `<p>`

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have this code, which I would like to make as small as possible.
As you can see, we are repeating alot of the same HTML code over, but with slight changes.

```
<?php if( ! $liked_before): // If not liked before, show the link a href?>
<a href="javascript:;" id="action-like">
    <div class="action_like" title="Like">
        <abbr title="Like">Like</abbr>
    </div>
</a>

<?php elseif($liked_before): // else dim it and make non clickable ?>

<p id="action-like" rel="liked_before">
        <div class="action_like" title="You Like this" style="opacity: 0.5;">
             <abbr title="You Like this">Like</abbr>
        </div>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Kind of stuck as to how I would condense this into less.
I also have the same code as above straight after, so I have 2 if else statements like this.
As you can see, the only things that change are:

- the `a href=...` tag to a `p` tag
- the title 'Like' -> 'You like this'
- the `p` tag must have the rel, as it is used in the javascript.

**Any ideas how I could make this leaner?**
Some sort of inline echo.
How would you do it?

Comment: Why do you want it make shorter, it will hurt the readibility?

Comment: All the lines are slightly different, except for the last </div>, this is probably the most readable.

Comment: tbh, I have a really large view file, and 2 of these if's are taking so much room across all my pages, I know this works, so I wanted to sort of 'minify' it, so my all my pages are slightly smaller, to help readability of other more important code.

Comment: If you use this construct a lot, maybe you should be making it into a function, define it once and have a one-line call every time you use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I would leave it as is.**

From your example, you're also modifying the HTML within the `<p>` or `<a>` tag (style and abbr attributes), and hacking together something to solve this trivial "problem" would only lead to less readible and harder to manage code. Especially from an efficiency standpoint, there's nothing to gain here.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be tidied up using better CSS. You can just use 1 a tag with the class 'liked' to differentiate the two. Very tidy code with just two different a tags.

Comment: Sounds so, but you want to change the behaviour to. If not like, it should be a clickable link/button, but if it's liked before it should be static. Unless you make it an 'unlike' link. :)

Comment: $('a.liked').click( alert('something'); );

Comment: $('a.likedbefore').click( alert('something different'));   Jquery

Comment: I know JQuery, but do you really want to depend on Javascript to disable the link? You can use JQuery to 'like'the page through AJAX and then disable the link, but when loading the entire page, I wouldn't take the chance.

Comment: On the other hand, the OP seems to have Javascript in the Href of the link. If the button depends on Javascript, I'd rely on Javascript to render it, or at least make it visible. You don't want links or buttons that don't respond at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose to

- Skip the `else` condition, you don't need it. It's either liked before or not.
- wrap it inside a p (or rather a div) in both cases.
- Output the `a` element only in case of the check. Perform the check twide, once for the opening and once for the closing.
- Set the opacity using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<html><?php echo $booleanCondition ? '<b>blah</b>' : '<i>blah</i>';?><html>
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but not practical for so much code really.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having the actual answer listed in answers:

Create a function that prints this, and keep calling the function as a one-line code throughout your php-file.

Comment: @JustAnil Who would have thought you didn't do that already. :-)

Answer (score -4):

Like this:

```
<?php 
   function getHtml($liked_before){
      $title='';
      $styleAttr='';
      if( ! $liked_before){ // If not liked before, show the link a href
          $title='Like';
      }
      else{ // else dim it and make non clickable
          $title='You Like this';
          $styleAttr=' style="opacity: 0.5;"';
      }

      $html='<div class="action_like" title="'.$title.'"'.$styleAttr.'><abbr title="'.$title.'">Like</abbr></div>';

      if( ! $liked_before){ // If not liked before, show the link a href
          $html='<a href="javascript:;" id="action-like">'.$html.'</a>';
      }
      else{ // else dim it and make non clickable
          $html='<p id="action-like" rel="liked_before">'.$html.'</p>';
      }
      return $html;
  }
?>
```

Comment: This makes it less readable. You kill any HTML highlighting that your editor supports and the lines are to long. Apart from that it's still the same code, only even less maintanable.

Comment: Obviously, you need a HTML highlighting editor for 3 tag elements. Not me.

Comment: Yep, and then it becomes four, and then you got half a page in a single echo. But I see you modified your answer to match the accepted answer. Maybe that will score you some points.

Comment: Yep, and it is still 3 for this case. I modified my answer to match my   suggestion.

Comment: it is not matter of "3 tags". It is matter of using templates at all. There are only 2 choices: to use templates or not. If yes - HTML should ALWAYS be as is. Otherwise the whole idea gets spoiled and code bloated. Once you get familiar with templates, you'll find your current code disgusting too :)

Comment: However it always makes me sick when I see an answer making the code worse than in the question, pulling the OP back. That's why -1

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Coming from a pseudo php developer who care about using templates or not... "makes me sick":what to say, perfection can hurt people sometimes... about your rating, I don't give a...